# VB.NET program requires administrator for Crystal Reports after install

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET app that utilizes Crystal Reports.

The program runs fine in Visual Studio and runs for me on any computer I have admin for.
For users without admin rights, it crashes and says "Load report failed." immediately upon load.

I don't think it's the issue of it not being able to load a report, if I put a msgbox as first line in my code, it doesn't make it that far.

I have read and tried several fixes; most point seem to point toward the Windows temp folder or some other permission.

Could someone point me in the right direction? VS2019, Crystal 13.0.31.4010

Comment: 1) Have you got references to the Crystal reports dll's in your project

2) For your users have you installed Crystal Reports Redistributable runtime

Comment: Hi, yes the references are there and Crystal runtime is installed on the user's computer. I can also right click the program, run as administrator, and the program will run just fine.